# having trouble creating a usable dictionary for my LP

Tags: python, pulp

I'm trying to build a LP in PULP - I'd like to take data from a csv file (saved locally), stick that data into a dictionary, then have the LP model loop through the dictionary to assign LP Variables.

Here's what I have so far (I'm somewhat new to python so please excuse the state of my code):

```
Columns = {}
with open('file','rU') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
        if columns:
            for i, value in enumerate(row):
               columns[i].append(value)
        else:
            # first row
           columns = [[value] for value in row]

as_dict = {c[0] : c[1:] for c in columns}

header1 = as_dict[header1]
header2 = as_dict[header2]
header3 = as_dict[header3]


# ideally, the dictionaries should look something like what's below:
# players = ['sb', 'ak', 'ee', 'cm', 'tk']
# points = {'sb':284.7, 'ak':257.8, 'ee':254.5, 'cm':250.9, 'tk':179.0}
# costs = {'sb':35, 'ak':25, 'ee':24, 'cm':23, 'tk':15}

players_vars = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("header1", header1, 0, cat="Integer")

model = pulp.LpProblem("model", pulp.LpMaximize)

model += pulp.lpSum([header2[i] * players_vars[i] for i in header1])

model += pulp.lpSum([header3[i] * players_vars[i] for i in header1]) <= 80


model.solve()
pulp.LpStatus[model.status]

for variable in model.variables():
    print "{} = {}".format(variable.name, variable.varValue)

print pulp.value(model.objective)`
```

here's the error I'm receiving:
model += pulp.lpSum([header2[i] * players_vars[i] for i in header1]) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str –

Does anyone have any insight to how this can be done? Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi and welcome to SO! what issues are you having with your code?

Comment: thanks for your quick comment. this is the error i'm receiving: model += pulp.lpSum([header2[i] * players_vars[i] for i in header1])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: please [edit] your question to add in the error.

Comment: i"ve added the error, thanks

Comment: It means that the items in `header1` are strings, and as such can not be used to index `header2` and `players_vars`. Diagnosing further is hard, as it depends on what you are reading in from the (unknown to us) file and it appears we don't have the full code (e.g. `header1`, `header2`, ... are not defined at first use).

Comment: If I may suggest, try reading your csv file using pandas: pd.read_csv(). Will likely make you data manipulation a whole lot easier given the existing functionality.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To maximise the chances of getting a good answer I'd recommend writing your question as a [mcve]. Basically share the lease amount of code you can to allow others to run it and get the same problem as you so they can fix it for you. Good luck!